# How to move files from certain directories to newly created directories based on their extension?

Tags: files, find, mv

My case is that I have multiple `.m3u8` and `.ts` files existing in their corresponding asset folder, e.g.,

```
/vod/CDN/ABC/index/.m3u8 and .ts 
/vod/CDN/DEF/index/.m3u8 and .ts
... 
/vod/CDN/XXX/index/.m3u8 and .ts
```

I want to find all the /index/ directories and separately move their `*.m3u8` and `*.ts` to the corresponding new-created directories. E.g., moving `*.m3u8` to `**/hls/index/**` and moving `*.ts` to `**/index/hls/**`

The result shall be like:

```
/vod/CDN/ABC/hls/index/.m3u8 
/vod/CDN/ABC/index/hls/.ts 
/vod/CDN/DEF/hls/index/.m3u8 
/vod/CDN/DEF/index/hls/.ts 
...
/vod/CDN/XXX/hls/index/.m3u8 
/vod/CDN/XXX/index/hls/.ts
```

Can some experts shed some lights on how to compose a bash script to do the above tasks?

Comment: Each /index contains many .m3u8 and many .ts files

Comment: what is the purpose of `hls` and its order?

Comment: Are these `index` directories always on the same level or could they be on different levels e.g. `GHI/JKL/index` ?

Comment: The index directories are on the same level. Only ABC/index or GHI/index

Answer (score -1):

This is a low-level solution but you could create the directories if there aren't too many and then use `` mv `find / -name *.extension` /destinationPath ``

Just repeat for each file extension, changing the file extension and destination path. Depending on how scattered your files are, choose an appropriate search point (I choose the root / ). This would be optimal if you only have several different extensions.